# How to sum unique values in an Oracle correlated sub-query?

Tags: oracle, subquery

Example invented for the purpose of asking the question:

```
, (SELECT SUM(CP.POPULATION)
   FROM SOMEUSER.CITY_POPULATION CP
   WHERE CP.COUNTRY_ID=CT.ID   --ALIAS FROM OUTER QUERY
) AS COUNTRY_CITY_POPULATION
```

Assume there can be duplicate rows for City ID and Population. When they're duplicate, the City ID and Population are exactly the same and we don't care about any other columns. We'd like to remove those duplicates before summing up. Wrapping `SELECT DISTINCT CP.CITY_ID, CP.POPULATION` with another `SELECT SUM(CP.POPULATION)` will not work here because we're sending outer query alias into the sub-query.

Open to ideas.

-- POPULATION OF CANADA

```
SELECT
    CT.COUNTRY_CODE
    , (SELECT SUM(CP.POPULATION)
       FROM SOMEUSER.CITY_POPULATION CP
       WHERE CP.COUNTRY_ID=CT.ID   --ALIAS FROM OUTER QUERY
      ) AS COUNTRY_CITY_POPULATION
FROM SOMEUSER.COUNTRY CT
WHERE CT.ID=1  --CANADA

:: SOMEUSER.CITY_POPULATION
RECORD_ID, COUNTRY_ID, CITY_ID, POPULATION NAME,     OTHER_COLUMNS_WE_DONT_CARE_ABOUT
1          1           1        5000000    TORONTO
2          1           1        5000000    TORONTO
```

I'm looking for a way to remove duplicate rows for CityID and Population.

Comment: Is city ID the same thing as country ID. I'm confused.

Comment: Within my invented example, CP.COUNTRY_ID and CP.CITY_ID are different values. The Distinct would be on CP.CITY_ID and CP.POPULATION, to select only one row for a given City.

Comment: A more complete standalone example would be much more useful and easier to understand. Use CTEs to provide the sample data, perhaps, and gove the output you're trying to achieve for that sample?

Comment: Alex, best I can do is that updated example. The actual issue is buried deep and I won't even attempt to show it. This correlated sub-query must use distinct before sum and an alias and that's what stops me.

Comment: It seems this is just part of a larger query. In most cases, such computations should be done much earlier in the query, not after you already aggregated bits of data. What would be most helpful would be a description of your base data, the overall requirement, and the desired output. The best solution may very well involve using analytic functions rather than aggregates, but it's impossible to tell from the little info you shared.

Answer (score 1):

I would first use a `join` instead of a correlation, and then you can do the `distinct` query without an issue:

```
SELECT    CT.COUNTRY_CODE
        , CCP.POPULATION AS COUNTRY_CITY_POPULATION
FROM      SOMEUSER.COUNTRY CT
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   CP.COUNTRY_ID, SUM(CP.POPULATION) AS POPULATION
           FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY_ID, CITY_ID, POPULATION
                     FROM   SOMEUSER.CITY_POPULATION
                    ) AS CP
           GROUP BY CP.COUNTRY_ID
          ) AS CCP
       ON CCP.COUNTRY_ID = CT.ID
WHERE     CT.ID=1  --CANADA
```

Of course, the outer query is a bit simple, and unnecessary (you can place the `WHERE` clause in the middle query), but I suppose your case might have more to it.

If for a given `CITY_ID` it is guaranteed you will not have two different `POPULATION` values (or if this happens, you want to take only one of them), then the following would be preferable:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   CP.COUNTRY_ID, SUM(CP.POPULATION) AS POPULATION
           FROM     (SELECT   COUNTRY_ID, CITY_ID, MIN(POPULATION) AS POPULATION
                     FROM     SOMEUSER.CITY_POPULATION
                     GROUP BY COUNTRY_ID, CITY_ID
                    ) AS CP
           GROUP BY CP.COUNTRY_ID
          ) AS CCP
       ON CCP.COUNTRY_ID = CT.ID
```

Comment: I extended the query just now with the latest info you provided, ... and a correction.

Comment: Would you not worry about the fact there are no `WHERE` clauses in those inner `SELECT`s? The table I'm sub-querying is quite large.

Comment: What is large? The number of cities in the world is not that large, that you should worry. On the positive side: in this case the inner query only has to execute once (even in the general case where you don't have an outer where clause), which should give a performance boost.